# Atualizar uma página web ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, atualização

Como atualizo uma página web ASP.Net?
Tenho uma página que possui dois `GridView` e preciso que essa página seja atualizada a cada 5 minutos.

Meus `GridView` estão assim:

```
<div class="GridMain">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvInformationPeriod" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="GridViewUser" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333" OnPageIndexChanging="gvInformationPeriod_PageIndexChanging" onrowdatabound ="gvInformationPeriod_RowDataBound" PageSize="100">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternativeUser" BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PeriodID" HeaderText="PeriodID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SchoolID" HeaderText="SchoolID" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOpen" HeaderText="Aberto Em" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Usuario" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="PCName" HeaderText="PC Name" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Closed" HeaderText="Closed" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#62AFC1" CssClass="GridPagerUser" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>


<div class="GridMain">
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvInformationProduct" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="GridViewUser" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333" OnPageIndexChanging="gvInformationProduct_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="100">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridAlternativeUser" BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Nome" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quantity" HeaderText="Quantidade" />
                        </Columns>
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#62AFC1" CssClass="GridPagerUser" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
```

Comment: você pode utilizar ajax neste caso, deixe o conteúdo de dados deste grid em uma tag específica `<div class='grid-content'></div>` por exemplo e use `setTimeInterval(loadDataInGrid(), 5000 * 60);`

Comment: Uso o setTimeInterval(loadDataInGrid(), 5000 * 60); dentro de um evento?

Comment: você pode usar dentro do evento onload da página, lembrando que loadDataInGrid é uma função que você irá implementar para carregar o conteúdo dentro da tag que deseja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300; url=http://sua_url.com/">
```

lembrando que o valor é em segundos, e como é uma tag html funciona em qualquer browser em qualquer versão.

Comment: Eu preciso colocar isso na minha master page? Dentro do arquivo Default.aspx não está funcionando.

Comment: o correto é estar entre o <head> mas se vc colocar na sua master page ela irá ficar atualizando todas as pages.. 
Diminui o valor dos segundos para testar.
Coloca somente na page que vc deseja

Comment: Não tem algo do tipo
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
onde vc coloca a códigos para head? na sua default.aspx ?